# AVPlayerStatus?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, avplayer

So I'm having trouble reading how I should use the `AVPlayerStatus` property

I have made the `@property(nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerStatus *status;` as the documentation tells me, but cant seem to find out how i use the

`AVPlayerStatusUnknows`..

I wanna use it in something like this

```
while(AVPlayerStatusUnknows)
{ 
      //DO SOMETHING 
}
```

can anyone help me here ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Patrick you cannot use the `AVPlayerStatus` objects because its not a class or a structure (or Union). Its an enumerator. we use it for checking a condition where in switch mostly (if we are creating it). The above method suggested by @Amorya is how to use `AVPlayerStatus`.

Hope this is making sense to you.

Check the documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Edit:

what you are looking for is something like this. I don't think that this will work or it might. but you will get the basic idea.

```
[yourActivityIndicator startAnimation];
while(yourAVPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown) {}
[yourActivityIndicator stopAnimation];
```

or if you just call the last 2 lines in a custom queue using GCD it will show you what you are looking for.

something like this, (not sure if this the exact syntax )

```
[yourActivityIndicator startAnimation];

dispatch_queue(^{
       while(yourAVPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown) {}
       [yourActivityIndicator stopAnimation];
 });
```

Comment: sorry but i did read the documentation, and it didnt make much sence for me.. i just wanna show a activity indicator while my avplayer is streaming.. not while playing the music, but while its buffing.. if this aint the method to do it, how can i do it then ? :/ 
and thanks for the anwser :)

Comment: so i just tryed yours and @Amorya's solution, still have some problems :/ when i use the dispatch_queue it gives me an error.. and with the player.status == avplayerstatusunknow, it freezes..

i have my player in my TableView, so when i press a cell, it starts playing the link..

hope you can see what i wanna do with my code:
http://pastebin.com/9J6uMN6N

Comment: did you check how to use GCD. I told you the screen will freeze in first case. so try to use Grand Central Dispatch

Comment: Found this site: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html
is that okay or ?

Comment: yes its a very good website. may be you can append it to your question when you able to achieve what you want.

Comment: i will :) but cant seem to figger out how this works :/ have tryed a lot of things with this dispatch, but cant get it working :/ i need to import the dispatch right ? and then, when i try use the code you posted, i still get warnings :/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make that property yourself: it's a property on an AVPlayer object.

You should be able to do `while (yourAVPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown) {}`. Substitute `yourAVPlayer` with an object of class AVPlayer.

Comment: thanks for the fast anwser :)
i inserted it but i got this error: 
error: 'AVPlayerStatusUnknows' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: It should be AVPlayerStatusUnknown not AVPlayerStatusUnknows (note the last letter).

Comment: arh ya.. got it working, gets no errors when i build.. but when i try it on the phone, it freezes when i press a cell in the tableview..
the function needs to be in my tableview, so when i press a cell, i get the AVPlayer url, and while its buffering, i need the indicator to be shows.. whats why i need this function, if i can use it for that purpse..